# Laravel Livewire Real Time Validation switching between classes

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, bootstrap-5

I'm wondering about how I can **switch between classes in Livewire real time form validation?**
let's imagine that i have a form with some input fields such as **(email)** inside the input class I have a **laravel directive** `@error('email') is-invalid @enderror` this will repeat **"is-invalid" clas**s when the form field is empty.
what I want to achieve is switching between "**is-invalid " and "is-valid"** classes the first one if the form field is empty and second one if the form field is filled.

**Here is my code :**

```
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function saveContact()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        Contact::create($validatedData);
    }
}

<form wire:submit.prevent="saveContact">
    <input type="text" wire:model="name" class="@error('name') is-invalid @enderror">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <input type="text" wire:model="email" class="@error('email') is-invalid @enderror">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <button type="submit">Save Contact</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the error bag `$errors` and check if it has an error with the existing `@error` blade directive to show the error message.

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="saveContact">
    <input type="text" wire:model="name" class="@if($errors->has('name')) is-invalid @else is-valid @endif">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <input type="text" wire:model="email" class="@if($errors->has('email')) is-invalid @else is-valid @endif">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <button type="submit">Save Contact</button>
</form>
```

I have used the `has` function from the error bag and the usual `@if` blade directive to achieve this.

Now if there is no error and input is valid, the `is-valid` class will be added.
Similarly if the validation fails, `is-invalid` class will be added.

Comment: It's even simpler: `@error('name') is-invalid @else is-valid @enderror`

Answer (score 0):

jhones,

You need to address it with javascript. See my answer below.

```
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function saveContact()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        Contact::create($validatedData);
    }
}

<form wire:submit.prevent="saveContact">
    <input type="text" wire:model="name" class="@error('name') is-invalid @else is-valid @enderror" id="name-input">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <input type="text" wire:model="email" class="@error('email') is-invalid @else is-valid @enderror" id="email-input">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <button type="submit">Save Contact</button>
</form>


<!-- javascript here: i use jquery syntaxe here -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name-input').change(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('is-invalid')
        });

        $('#email-input').change(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('is-invalid')
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Explanation**

I modify the HTML as following:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="name" class="@error('name') is-invalid @else is-valid @enderror" id="name-input">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

<input type="text" wire:model="email" class="@error('email') is-invalid @else is-valid @enderror" id="email-input">
```

I add an id to each input to be able to call them in the script later.
Also i add the class "is-valid" if the server didn't return an error msg.

Hope this solution helps you. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend you can use ;

```
<input id="email" class="form-control @if($errors->has('form.email')) is-invalid @else {{ $is_valid }} @endif" name="email" type="email" wire:model.lazy="form.email">
@error('form.email')<label id="email-error" class="error invalid-feedback" for="email" >{{ $message }}</label> @enderror
```

And class is ;

```
public function updated($name)
{
    $a= $this->validateOnly($name, [
        'form.email' => 'required|email',
        'form.password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($a) {
        $this->is_valid='is-valid'; 
    }
    else {
        $this->is_valid='';
    }
}
```